# Inside of a class, why `auto b() -> decltype(a()) {}` works, but `decltype(a()) b() {}` does not?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider following code: [(Ideone)](http://ideone.com/OXG7s1)

```
struct S
{
    int a() {return 0;}
    decltype(a()) b() {return 1;}
};
```

It gives me following error:

> error: cannot call member function 'int S::a()' without object

On the other hand, this code compiles fine: [(Ideone)](http://ideone.com/JXOghO)

```
struct S
{
    int a() {return 0;}
    auto b() -> decltype(a()) {return 1;}
};
```

Why one example works, but another fails to compile?

Is compiler behavior fully correct in both examples?

If compiler is correct, then why the standard mandates such strange behavior?

Comment: for those wondering which compiler this is: it looks like gcc, though both gcc and clang reject the first and accept the second.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `a` is a non-static member function, `a()` is interpreted as `(*this).a()`. Quoting in part from [expr.prim.general]/3,

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class `X`, the expression `this`
>   is a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`” between the optional *cv-qualifer-seq* and the end of the
>   *function-definition*, *member-declarator*, or *declarator*. It shall not appear before the optional *cv-qualifier-seq*
>   and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function (although its type and value
>   category are defined within a static member function as they are within a non-static member function).

The *trailing-return-type* comes after the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* (omitted in your examples, since `S::b` is not cv-qualified) so `this` can appear there, but it cannot appear before.

Comment: ...and this is because you don't know the type of `this` until you've seen the cv-qualifier-seq.

Comment: Also, technically, that `a()` => `(*this).a()` transformation never takes place - it only happens "in a context where `this` can be used" - and then it breaks [\[expr.prim.id\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but it's because the language designers love you, and want to give you as much freedom to use `this` as they possibly can :)

Answer (score 10):

A few additions to [@Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37038912/4143855):

1. In the first example, the `a()` is *not* transformed to `(*this).a()`. That transformation is specified in [[class.mfct.non-static]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct.non-static#3) and only takes place "in a context where `this` can be used". Without this transformation, the code is then ill-formed for violating [[expr.prim.id]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2):

   > An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or non-static
   >   member function of a class can only be used:
   >
   > - as part of a class member access ([expr.ref]) in which the object expression refers to the member's class<sup>63</sup> or a class
   >     derived from that class, or
   > - to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
   > - if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

   by using the *id-expression* `a`, which denotes a non-static member function, outside the allowed contexts.
2. The fact that the transformation to class-member access doesn't take place is important because it makes the following code valid:

   ```
   struct A {
       int a;
       decltype(a) b();
   };
   ```

   If `decltype(a)` above were transformed into `decltype((*this).a)`, then the code would be ill-formed.
3. `*this` has a special exemption from the usual rule that the object in a class member access must have complete type ([[expr.prim.this]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#2)):

   > Unlike the object expression in other contexts, `*this` is not required to be of complete type for purposes of class member access ([expr.ref]) outside the member function body.