# Example where trailing return type must be used, because the problem cannot be solved the old way

Tags: c++

Is there any case, where we must use trailing return type, because the problem cannot be phrased in the old way?

`auto fn() -> int;` can be easily transformed to the old way: `int fn();`.

I wonder, is there an example, where this transformation is not possible. The most straighforward example, when we refer to function parameters in the return type, seems to be solvable by using `declval`.

Note: don't consider lambdas here, where we must use trailing return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One bizzare example I can think of, which needs some prerequisites.

Consider a function which cannot use auto return type deduction (e.g. it has multiple return values which cannot be deduced to the same type) and uses generic function from C++ concepts. Then you don't have a type to use for `std::declval` and auto deduction won't work:

```
auto foo(auto x)
// -> decltype(x) // comment this out to fix
{
    if(x > 0) return x;
    return -1; // requires int to be implicite castable to type of x
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3ca9adda8aee3a8)

Comment: "*uses generic function from C++ concepts*" Which is equivalent to having a template header. And even in lambdas in C++20, you don't need to use `auto` like that. So I don't see how this fulfills the OP's requirement of this being a "must use". You could solve the problem in more verbose ways, which the OP apparently sees as fine, since `std::declval` is totally OK for the OP.

Answer (score 7):

In a trailing return type, you're allowed to apply `decltype` to `this` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038832/inside-of-a-class-why-auto-b-decltypea-works-but-decltypea)).

With the old syntax, you'd have to spell the class name manually... which you can't do if the class is unnamed!

<sup>(Or if the member function is generated with a macro, so the class name isn't known.)</sup>

```
struct
{
    auto foo() -> decltype(this)
    {
        return this;
    }

    /*
    decltype(this) foo() // error: invalid use of 'this' at top level
    {
        return this;
    }
    */
} x;
```

I admit that this is a slightly unrealistic example, and you can easily work around it by naming the class, but I couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: Since C++14 we have “auto” return type deduction. This example can be easily worked around by simple omitting `decltype` at all. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d9aad2d59b1bddb)

Comment: @user1810087 "...cannot be solved the **old** way", if you allow return type deduction I guess there is no example that needs the trailing